# Change row width of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` Where I have set all 3 row widths to `33.33%` in the designer, but when I change the width dynamically through code, the column width stays a defined value.

Does anyone have any way to change the width of a row dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to access the index of the ColumnStyles collection:

```
With TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles(1)
  .SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
  .Width = 32
End With
```

If you are trying to set the width of a single row, then that really isn't possible unless you span the column using `SetColumnSpan` to make multiple columns into a single column.  That requires a control to be placed inside the cell.